# Automatically get items from observable when an event is fired without an eventbus

Tags: java, android, events, rx-java, rx-android

What is the best way to automatically retrieve new items from an observable when you have an external event that tells you that you should?

For example , lets say I have and `ItemRepository` which implements a `getAllItems()` method (which returns `Observable<List<Item>>` from a webservice) , and then, an external event (like a push notification) tells my application that the data needs to be refreshed. (also the `ItemRepository` is used in a `Presenter` and that presenter has called the `getAllItems` and on it's `onNext`, it's data s refreshed.)

I know this can be done easily with event bus (listen for that event , when its fired, fetch again) , but I'm just wondering if it's possible to do that completely automatically.

Thanks.

*edit*

This is a solution that I came up with , with the help of SQLBrite library ,  but not sure if its the best or cleanest way to do it.
we have a PublishSubject that the events get sent to:

`PublishSubject<Object> updateEvent;`

and in the getAllItems() method , we check for the events from that subject:

```
public Observable<List<Item>> getAll() {
    Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Item>> subscribe = subscriber -> {
        updateEvent.subscribe(s -> {
            subscriber.onNext(dbItemRepository.getAll());
        });
        subscriber.onNext(dbItemRepository.getAll());// for the first call
    };
    final Observable<List<Item>> automatonObservable = Observable.create(subscribe) =
            .onBackpressureLatest()
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .onBackpressureLatest();
    return automatonObservable;
}
```

Comment: callbacks ? LocalBoradcastManager ?

Comment: @tamtom please elaborate about implementing callbacks in this case , thank you.

Comment: Please, check my answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Rodrigo Henriques has the right idea, but we need to change it a bit according to your question:

```
public static Observable<String> observeRepositoryUpdates(ItemsRepository repo, Observable<Void> updateTrigger) {
  updateTrigger
    //you can insert observeOn here
    .flatMap(event -> repository.getAllItems());
}

public static void doWork() {
  ItemsRepository repo = new ItemsRepository();
  PublishSubject<Void> updateTrigger = PublishSubject.create();

  observeRepositoryUpdates(repo, updateTrigger)
    .subscribe(items -> System.out.println(items.toString());

  updateTrigger.onNext(null);//trigger update
}
```

Depending on your event, it doesn't have to be a `PublishSubject`, any other observable can trigger repository update.

If your event happens frequently and you want to drop already running repository update and start new one, you can use operator [switchMap](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#switchMap(rx.functions.Func1)).

Comment: If you want to get the item from the event and from the first call you can use : `itemRepository.getAll().mergeWith(itemUpdateEvent.flatMap(event -> itemRepository.getAll()));`

Comment: In this case it is better to use `concat` instead of `mergeWith`, to be sure, that at first we get items from repo and  only then observe update events.
Because `concat` waits when first sequence completes and then subscribes to second one (while merge doesn't wait for completion of first).

Comment: Thanks , this answer with combination of the comments is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Subject.

Check it out.

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void testSample() throws Exception {
        ItemRepository itemRepository = new ItemRepository();

        itemRepository.getAllItems()
                .doOnNext(items -> System.out.println("Initializing emission..."))
                .flatMap(Observable::from)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);

        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

        items.add(new Item("First"));
        items.add(new Item("Second"));

        itemRepository.publishNewItems(items);

        items.add(new Item("Third"));
        items.add(new Item("Fourth"));

        itemRepository.publishNewItems(items);
    }

    public class ItemRepository {
        private PublishSubject<List<Item>> itemsListSubject = PublishSubject.create();

        public Observable<List<Item>> getAllItems() {
            return itemsListSubject;
        }

        public void publishNewItems(List<Item> items) {
            itemsListSubject.onNext(items);
        }
    }

    public class Item {
        private String name;

        public Item(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Item{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

The code above will print:

```
Initializing emission...
Item{name='First'}
Item{name='Second'}
Initializing emission...
Item{name='First'}
Item{name='Second'}
Item{name='Third'}
Item{name='Fourth'}
```

So, you have one observable that will emit a item list any time that you want.

I recommend you to see Subject documentation [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html).

Hope that it helps.

Best regards.

Comment: thanks for your info , but this is different because you are generating your data , but in the case of my question , we just want the `getAllItems()` to emit new items as fast as a new event comes in. I've already developed a solution with `PublishSubject` which the `getAllItems` listens to (as the event) and when an item from that subject is emitted , it gets the items , but I don't think that iss the best idea.

Comment: I edited my question my with method , please check it , thanks.

Comment: Buddy, I've used this solution in my project to achieve the same result as you. I don't think that you get my sample right. As long as you receive new data info, you just have to emit this to your publish subject and he will update their subscribers.

Comment: I know what you tried , but the thing is , I don't get the items from the event.The event is just telling me that its time to update and the getAllItems() has to be called again (if it had the data in the event , I would for sure use your method , as its simple and efficient)